# crud mvc en php no logro conectar con bd

Tags: php, mysqli, .htaccess, debian, namespace

tengo un `crud` en `php` que funciona de diez en `windows` pero lo tengo que pasar al servidor, que esta en `linux (debian 9)`, y las vistas con `url` amigables funcionan osea me carga las pantallas, pero no me trae los datos de la `bd` .-
toda la aplicación tiene un estructura `MVC` , las cuales redirecciono con un `autoload` junto que `namespace` , tmb tengo un archivo `.htaccess`, que son los que creo esta el inconveniente , en cuanto al servidor, esta habilitado el `mod_rewrite` del `apache2` , y dentro de las configuraciones de `/etc/apache2/000-default.conf` cambie las opciones `AllowOverride none` por `AllowOverride All`, ya no se que otra configuración estoy pasando por alto

mi archivo .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine ON 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

mi archivo autoload.php

```
    <?php namespace Config;

class Autoload{

        public static function run(){
            spl_autoload_register(function($class){
                    $ruta = str_replace("\\", "/", $class) . ".php";
                        require_once $ruta;
            });
        }
}
?>
```

mi archivo request.php

```
    <?php namespace Config;
    class Request{
        private $controlador;
        private $metodo;
        private $argumento;
        public function __construct(){
            if(isset($_GET['url'])){
                $ruta = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'url', FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);
                $ruta = explode('/', $ruta);
                $ruta = array_filter($ruta);
                if($ruta[0] == "index.php"){
                        $this->controlador = "estudiantes";
                }else{
                        $this->controlador = strtolower(array_shift($ruta)); 
                    }
                $this->metodo = strtolower(array_shift($ruta));
                if(!$this->metodo){
                        $this->metodo = "index";
                    }
                    $this->argumento = $ruta;
            }else{
                $this->controlador = "template";
                $this->metodo = "index";
            }
        }       
        public function getControlador(){
            return $this->controlador;
        }
        public function getMetodo(){
            return $this->metodo;
        }
        public function getArgumento(){
            return $this->argumento;
        }
    }
?>
```

mi archivo enrutador.php

```
    <?php namespace Config;
    class Enrutador{
        public static function run(Request $request){
                    $controlador= $request->getControlador() . "controller";
                    $ruta= ROOT . "Controllers" . DS . $controlador . ".php";
                    $metodo = $request->getMetodo();
                    if ($metodo == "index.php") {
                        $metodo = "index";
                    }
                    $argumento = $request->getArgumento();
                    if (is_readable($ruta)) {
                        require_once $ruta;
                        $mostrar = "Controllers\\" . $controlador;
                        $controlador = new $mostrar;

                        if (!isset($argumento)) {
                            $datos = call_user_func(array($controlador, $metodo));
                        }else{
                            $datos = call_user_func_array(array($controlador, $metodo), $argumento);
                        }
                    }
                    $ruta = ROOT . "Views" . DS . $request->getControlador() . DS . $request->getMetodo()  . ".php";
                    if (is_readable($ruta)) {
                        require_once $ruta;
                    }else{
                        print "no se encontro la ruta";
                    }
                        print  $ruta;
        }
    }
?>
```

mi archivo  index.php de la raiz del sitio

```
<html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
            define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
            define('ROOT', realpath(dirname(__FILE__)).DS);
            //define('URL', "http://localhost/proyecto/");

            define('URL', "http://192.168.1.19/proyecto/");

            require_once "Models/Conexion.php";
            require_once "Config/Autoload.php";
            Config\Autoload::run();
            require_once "Views/template.php";
            Config\Enrutador::run(new \Config\Request());
        ?>

    </body>
```

el archivos index.php de la carpeta Views donde tendria que aparecer el datos

```
<div class="box-principal">
<h3 class="titulo">Areas</h3>
    <div class="panel panel-success">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
                <td><h3 class="panel-title"><a href="<?php echo URL;?>areas/crear" class="btn btn-success">Crear Nuevo</a></h3></td>
                <td>
                    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0" action="<?php echo URL;?>areas/buscar" method="POST">
                  <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" name="Areas" placeholder="Areas">
                  <button class="btn btn-secondary my-2 my-sm-0"  type="submit">Buscar</button>
                </form>
                </td>
        </table>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
                <thead>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>Areas</th>  
                    <th colspan="3">Action</th>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <?php while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($datos)){ ?>
                    <tr>
                    <td  scope="row"> <?php echo $row['ID_Areas'];?></td>
                    <td> <?php echo $row['Areas'];?></td>
                    <td>
                    <a href="<?php echo URL;?>areas/ver/<?php echo $row['ID_Areas'];?>" class="btn btn-primary">Ver</a>
                    <a href="<?php echo URL;?>areas/editar/<?php echo $row['ID_Areas'];?>" class="btn btn-primary">Editar</a>
                    <a href="<?php echo URL;?>areas/eliminar/<?php echo $row['ID_Areas'];?>" class="btn btn-primary">Eliminar</a>
                    </td>
                    </tr>
                <?php } ?>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
```

sale de error

```
Notice: Undefined variable: datos in /home/tor/public_html/proyecto/Views/areas/index.php on line 57

Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in /home/tor/public_html/proyecto/Views/areas/index.php on line 57
```

mi modelo de areas

```
<?php namespace Models;

//include_once("Conexion.php");
 class Areas{
    private $id;
    private $Areas;
    private $con;


        public function __construct(){
            $this->con = new Conexion();
         }


        public function set($atributo, $contenido){
            return $this->$atributo = $contenido;
        }

        public function get($atributo){
            return $this->$atributo;
        }

        public function listar(){
            $sql= "SELECT * FROM areas";
            $resultado = $this->con->consultaRetorno($sql);
            return $resultado;
        }

        public function add(){
                $sql="INSERT INTO areas (Areas)
                VALUES('{$this->Areas}')";
                $this->con->consultaSimple($sql);                
        }

        public function delete(){
            $sql="DELETE FROM areas WHERE ID_Areas = '{$this->id}'";
            $this->con->consultaSimple($sql);
        }

        public function edit(){
            $sql="UPDATE areas SET Areas = '{$this->Areas}' WHERE ID_Areas = '{$this->id}'";
            $this->con->consultaSimple($sql);
        }

        public function view(){

            $sql="SELECT * FROM areas WHERE ID_Areas = '{$this->id}'";
            $datos = $this->con->consultaRetorno($sql);
            $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($datos);
            return $row;    
        }

        public function bus(){
            $sql2="SELECT * FROM areas WHERE Areas = '{$this->Areas}'";
            $dato = $this->con->consultaRetorno($sql2);
            $num = mysqli_num_rows($dato);
            if ($num != 0) {
            $sql="SELECT * FROM areas WHERE Areas = '{$this->Areas}'";
            $datos = $this->con->consultaRetorno($sql);
            $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($datos);
            return $row;
            }else{
                $num=0;
                return $num;

        }

    }
}
```

?>

mi archivo controlador

```
<?php namespace Controllers;

use Models\Areas as Areas;

    class areasController{
        private $areas;

        public function __construct(){
            $this->areas = new Areas();
        }

        public function index(){
          $datos = $this->areas->listar();
          return $datos;
        }

        public function crear(){
            if($_POST){

                $this->areas->set("Areas", $_POST['Areas']);
                $this->areas->add();
                header("Location: " . URL . "areas");
            }   
        }

        public function eliminar($id){

            if(!$_POST){
                $this->areas->set("id", $id);
                $datos = $this->areas->view();
                return $datos;
            }else{
                $this->areas->set("id", $id);
                $this->areas->delete();
                header("Location: " . URL . "areas");   
            }

        }

        public function ver($id){
            $this->areas->set("id",$id);
            $datos = $this->areas->view();
            return $datos;
        }
        public function buscar(){
            //echo "cedula: " . $this->cedula;
            if($_POST['Areas'] == ""){
                header("Location: " . URL . "areas");   
            }else{
                $this->areas->set("Areas",$_POST['Areas']);
                $datos = $this->areas->bus();
                return $datos;
            }
        }


        public function editar($id){
                if(!$_POST){
                    $this->areas->set("id", $id);
                    $datos = $this->areas->view();
                    return $datos;
                }else{
                    $this->areas->set("Areas", $_POST['Areas']);        
                    $this->areas->edit();
                    header("Location: " . URL . "areas");
            }
        }
}   
$areas = new areasController();
```

?>

mi archivo conexion.php que se encuentra dentro de la carpeta Models

```
<?php namespace Models;

class Conexion{
    // CONSULTA ORIGINAL
    private $datos= array(
        "host" => "localhost",
        "user" => "tor",
        "pass" => "pass",
        "db" => "base"
    );
    private $con;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->con = new \mysqli($this->datos['host'],$this->datos['user'],
        $this->datos['pass'],$this->datos['db']);

    }
    public function consultaSimple($sql){
        $this->con->query($sql);
    }
    public function consultaRetorno($sql){
        $datos = $this->con->query($sql);
        return $datos;
    }
```

agrego una imagen de la estructura del proyecto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo extraño que me sucede es que en un servidor `windows` me funciona perfecto, crea modifica y elimina datos , yo los probé en varios servidores del tipo `linux` , que fueron la distribución debían 7 y 9 , ya no se que puede ser lo que estaría fallando.

agradezco cualquier consejo que tengan. 
desde ya gracias .-

Comment: ¿index.php obtiene de Enrutador la variable $datos? Veo que el autoload hace include en lugar de require, ¿puede ser que tengas algún archivo con mayúsculas/minúsculas, no se esté incluyendo y provoque que $datos quede undefined? Para linux es diferente el archivo "test.php" de Test.php" pero para windows son el mismo. Lo último que se me ocurre es que el método al que llames del controlador devuelva algo que no esperas.

Comment: si asi el enrutador le retorna el dato  , ya cambie el autoload , voy a unificar el nombre de los archivos ya sea por minuscula o mayuscula a ver que pasa. edite la pregunta con mas detalles

Comment: @ArielMontero En el archivo enrutador.php fijate que cuando armas el controlador a llamar lo haces con minuscula, es decir queda como `loqueseacontroller` en lugar de `loqueseaController`, esta liena me refiero `$controlador= $request->getControlador() . "controller";`

Comment: @David;@Xerif , muchisimas gracias , cambie el controller por Controller y funciono todo , de nuevo muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Los nombres de los archivos son sensibles a minúsculas y a mayúsculas en linux, en el archivo `enrutador.php` fijate que cuando armas el nombre del controlador lo haces con minúscula, es decir queda como `loqueseacontroller` en lugar de `loqueseaController`, esta líena me refiero:

```
$controlador= $request->getControlador() . "controller";
```

Esto debería quedar:

```
$controlador= $request->getControlador() . "Controller";
```